# Reasigning a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Can anyone please help me understand the following. I am reassigning a pointer and use a temporary value to get the contents it points. I see no reason why case 1 should work and case 2 shouldn't.

// Case 1 :This works:

```
void main (void){

    unsigned int  nr1;
    unsigned int  nr2;
    unsigned int  * ptr_int;
    unsigned int temp1_value;
    unsigned int temp2_value;

    while(1){

        nr1 = 0x1234;
        ptr_int= &nr1;
        temp1_value  = *(ptr_int); // Copy nr1 to temp1_value

        nr2 = 0x5678;
        ptr_int= &nr2;
        temp2_value  = *(ptr_int); // Copy nr2 to temp2_value

    }
}
```

// Case 2 : This doesn't work (if I go step by step, temp1_value does not change)

```
void main (void){

    unsigned int  nr1;
    unsigned int  nr2;
    unsigned int  * ptr_int;
    unsigned int temp1_value;
    unsigned int temp2_value;

    while(1){

        nr1 = 0x1234;
        ptr_int= &nr1;
        temp1_value  = *(ptr_int); //Copy nr1 to temp1_value

        nr2 = 0x5678;
        ptr_int= &nr2;
        temp1_value  = *(ptr_int); //Copy nr2 to temp1_value

    }
}
```

I am sure this is something basic but I cannot point my finger on it.

Am I not allowed to reassign a pointer?

Thank you.

Edit: It's embedded C. The target is a 8051 microcontroller.

Comment: temp1_value is always the same as nr2. (0x5678)

Comment: Did you mean for the last assignment to assign to temp2_value instead of temp1_value as it does now?

Comment: Perhaps your compiler has optimized away the first few lines, since they aren't being used for anything anyway.  Try putting some printf's in that print out the value of temp1_value after each assignment, that will force it not to optimize.

Comment: The whole loop might be optimized ayway.

Comment: i am sorry, maybe i am blind, could somebody show me where is the difference between case 1 and 2?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr, in the second example the same targe is reused (temp1 vs. temp2)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It doesn't compile? You get the wrong output? What happens when you declare the variables as volatile?

Comment: which ide are you using? maybe you can show us the asm?

Comment: If I put printf this works fine. The value of temp1_value changes accordingly. I've seen that in one instance (wrong one) the pointer is stored on data memory and in the second one the pointer is store in xdata. Strangely enough, if "force" the assignment in the xdata, it still doesn't work. However, declaring temp1_value as volatile does the trick.

Comment: if you want to fix this, you can do it by making `temp1_value` `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Jeremy and Lundin.

In case someone else stumbles on something similar, changing

```
unsigned int temp1_value;
```

to

```
volatile unsigned int temp1_value;
```

gives me the expected behavior.

Comment: And this is why you should avoid having optimizations enabled in your debug build.